# How to enter math equations into xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, math, load, equations

I'm working on a project in my spare time, so i'm pretty new to xcode. 
I need to write a lot of equations and symbols in this app, and would it be easier to just load the equations and pictures? I could write them in latex before loading the pdfs into xcode.

However, this would lead to a lot of small pictures in the text, and i am contemplating whether it would be better just to write the entire thing in latex and just load a picture in instead.

How does these two options affect the speed of the app?

Advice on whether any of these solutions are even viable is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear how you're wanting to use the equations, but one option that may work for you is to use a combination of Doxygen and LaTeX or Mathjax.

Doxygen is used to generate HTML/PS documentation of your source code -- which may be what you need, or you could use it to generate the equation images which you can then load into the app.  The advantage is that the equations are defined in one place (the source).  See the documentation: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/formulas.html

Another great thing about Doxygen is that you can use the LaTeX syntax for formulas.

Another possibility could be to use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to render equations from HTML and then use a web control in your app to show the equations directly from HTML.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to help! 
I am going to have to explain formulas, which means i have to display them alone and then use some of the symbols like "f(x)" mid sentence. What do you think is the easiest solution and what is the best solution?

Comment: What do you mean by 'explain formulas in the app'? What kind of app is it? How are you displaying data to the user? Do you know all the formulas you're going to need beforehand (ie so you can install static content)? Can you use a web control to display it?